# how to do this design with flex box instead of grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a design that I make it with HTML, CSS using grid. But I want to remake it with flex box instead of grid. This design is made with grid:
[image: this design is made with grid]

**source code:**

*DEMO:*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  gap: 10px 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.parent div {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I made a design that looks like this but using flex box: [image: this design is made with flex box]

**source code:**

*DEMO:*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.parent div {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.01px dotted black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32%;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div style = "margin-left: 0px;">1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div  style = "margin-right: 0px;">4</div>
      <div style = "margin-left: 0px;">5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div  style = "margin-right: 0px;">8</div>
      <div style = "margin-left: 0px;">9</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My question:**

-Can I create this design by flex box in a better way?

Comment: Except the numbers that are not align correctly in your flex box, what is the problem ? Because result look like the same

Comment: Is the code I wrote bad?

Comment: @fadisafou check my answer below and see if you like it more like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how i would do it, first of all avoiding styles in html tags, and using space-between istead of margins to locate the elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row div {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.01px dotted black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div>9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```